# Problem with passing XML element from Oracle database to ElementTree (Python xml parser)

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, cx-oracle

i want to get an XML file out of a database, manipulate it with ElementTree and then insert it into another database. Getting the file works just fine, i can print it in it's entirety. However, whenever i try to get it through the parser it returns the error "no element found".

Here is the code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"here and there")

try:
    dsn_tns_source = cx_Oracle.makedsn('censored for obvious reasons')
    con_source = cx_Oracle.connect(cx_Oracle.makedsn('same here'))

except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as err:
    print("Connection DB error:", err)


try:
    cur_source = con_source.cursor()

    source_select = cur_source.execute("working SELECT")

    print(source_select)

    for row in source_select:
        x = row[(len(row) - 1)]  # This is the XML
        print("source_row: ", x)
        tree = et.parse(x)
        root = tree.getroot()
        print(root)
        print(et.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
    for col in cur_source.description:
        print("source_col: ", col)
```

Apparently I am not passing "x" correctly, however, the entire XML should be help in that variable at the point of calling it. Most tutorials only show how to insert local files so i thought simply using the variable would be sufficient.
The error message is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\basler_benchmark\main.py", line 24, in <module>
     tree = et.parse(x)
  File "C:\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1229, in parse
     tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 580, in parse
     self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`.parse()` specifically parses files.

If `x` is a string, use `.fromstring()`:

```
root = et.fromstring(x)
```

If `x` is something else, it must be turned into a string first. For `cx_Oracle.LOB` objects, calling `.read()` should do the trick:

```
root = et.fromstring(x.read())
```

Comment: when i use fromstring i get:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'cx_Oracle.LOB'
that's why i assumed it was actually a file and not a string.
it works just fine with BeautifulSoup, however i was told not to use it due to an aversion towards non-standard libraries.

Comment: @Knolfuns You said, "this is XML", so I assumed `x` was an XML string. When you `print(x.read())`, what gets printed?

Comment: oh dear lord, i might have massively confused things. if i pull it from the database could it be a lob and not an xml?
when i use print(x.read()) i get the whole thing (<abc1><def1></def1></abc1>) printed in console.
sorry for the confusion, i'm quite new to working with files located in oracle dbs.

Comment: @Knolfuns Well it already told you it was a LOB (*"a bytes-like object is required, not 'cx_Oracle.LOB'"*). I don't know if a `cx_Oracle.LOB` is a file-like object, but it does not seem like it, despite the `.read()` method. When you try `et.fromstring(x.read())`, it *should* work, I think? Whether that's the most elegant way to do it, I don't know either. For reasonably small XML sizes it should hardly make any difference, though.

Comment: it kinda works  but after i use getroot() i get the structure of the xml but everything appears to be empty. nothing inside the child tags.

Comment: @Knolfuns That's a different issue. Write the data to file and have a closer look at it. But when ElementTree parses it successfully but it still looks strange to you, chances are that something is wrong with the data itself.

Comment: I managed to get what i need, i didn't realize that you have to iterate over the entire thing. I thought it'd work like beautiful soup and you can just search for the word and get the data within the found field.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Knolfuns You can, probably by using XPath to navigate to the node you want. That should be easier than iterating manually.

Comment: I haven't thought about that, i will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The error was

a) That what I had in x was not an XML file but a LOB and that i had to import it with

```
et.fromstring(x.read())
```

like Tomalak answered/commented and

b) that I didn't realize that you HAVE TO iterate over the entire thing in order to be able to use .text to get what's inside the field/tag.

So the solution looks like this:

```
    for row in source_select:
        x = row[(len(row) - 1)]
        tree = et.ElementTree(et.fromstring(x.read()))
        root = tree.getroot()
        for aref in root.iter('name_of_tag'):
            print(aref.text)
```

Comment: You can say `root = et.fromstring(x.read())`, there is no need to construct an `ElementTree` instance first. You can use `.iterfind('./some/xpath/expression')` to single out specific nodes.